# VB.NET Append text to the end of a line in an exiting CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, append

How can I append text to the end a line in a text file with lines already there in VB.NET?

For example my text file looks like this:

header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
stuff1,stuff2,stuff3

and I want to add new text to the end of each line so it looks like this:
header1,header2,header3,newheader
value1,value2,value3,newvalue
stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,newstuff

I know that in Perl you can point to the line and then act on it, is there some VB.net way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file isn't too big, the simplest is, probably, to use the IO.File.ReadAllLines method to read the file into memory and modify the data and write it back with the WriteAllLines method.

For very large files you're probably looking at reading each line modifying it and writing it to a different file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file is rather big. Which is why I ask =)

Comment: Then you're left with sequential access.  You can optimize by reading large chunks into memory.